# Do I need to Initialize the page object in my Spec file with Protractor?

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, pageobjects

This is the style I have now. A fairly simple page object model.

```
var loginPage = require('../pages/loginPage');
var homePage = require('../pages/homePage');

describe('Login', function () {

  it('Valid Login should successfully reach the home page, with valid page title.', function () {
    browser.driver.get("https://dev.mysite.com/");
    loginPage.login('TestUser', 'TestPassword');
    homePage.getHeaderText();
    //expect header text to equal "My header"
  });
});
```

The official Protractor Style Guide suggests doing it like this. It appears to create an object for the page unique to each test. Is there an advantage to doing this?

```
var loginPage = require('../pages/loginPage');
var homePage = require('../pages/homePage');

describe('Login', function () {
var loginPageObj = new loginPage();
var homePageObj = new homePage();

  it('Valid Login should successfully reach the home page, with valid page title.', function () {
    browser.driver.get("https://dev.mysite.com/");
    loginPageObj.login('TestUser', 'TestPassword');
    //or should homePageObj be initialized here,
    //right before it is first used?
    homePageObj.getHeaderText();
    //expect header text to equal "My header"
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to initial home page in the spec.
You can have it return from  loginPageObj.login('TestUser', 'TestPassword'); 
Login login page object would look something like this :

```
var loginPage = function() {
this.txtUserName = element(by.xpath('xpath'));
this.txtPassword = element(by.xpath('xpath'));
this.login = function(strUsername,strPassword) {
        var self = this;
        this.txtUserName.isPresent().then(function(status){
            if(status){
                self.txtUserName.sendKeys(strUsername);
                self.txtPassword.sendKeys(strPassword);
                self.btnLogin.click();
            }
        });
        return require('../Pages/HomePage.js');     
    }}
module.exports = new loginPage();
```

Using it in the test spec

```
var homePage = loginPage.login(browser.params.username, browser.params.password);
homePage.getHeaderText();
```

Comment: Makes sense. I see now that I have `module.exports = new HomePage();` in my page object, and the protractor example only has `module.exports = HomePage;` therefore, they have to initialize it in the spec.

Answer (score 2):

It is still good to use the way how your own style has.

And why the official guide says so is, 
it will help to make the test files independent. 
If you instantiate as objects you can define your scope well.
And better understanding/ readability of the code.

I too follow your own style previously.

Now I am working with typescript/protractor combo. Where the New style guide gives more sense.

But both the style functionally works perfectly nothing wrong with your own style. :)